# Solr - Core Specific Query Time Boost

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying to determine best practice for boosting a set of static terms on query.

For example, I currently have 10 cores.  Each core will have it's own static set of terms to boost (e.g. Core1=UPC^5, Core2=UPC^10, etc.). Using the links below I'm able to manually boost a query based on these terms, but I'm trying to determine how others might have accomplished this same or a similar task.  From a performance standpoint, would a simple database or reference file that is read on every query be sufficient?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Solr Version: 6.2.1

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ

https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/scoring.html

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how often these boosts change; the easiest part if you just have a small amount of them is to add them from your query / controller layer, either retrieved directly from the code (i.e. `getBoostForCore(name);`) or from a SQL query if necessary.

If they never change and you want them to be available from multiple applications, you can add them directly to your core configuration as static parameters [to the core using `appends`/`invariants`/`defaults`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Request+Parameters+API).